# Android studio is stuck while downloading SDKs

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, failed-installation

Today I had opened Android Studio for the first time and while it was downloading SDK it was stuck on downloading the first SDK.

Hence it was looping [this](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip) url continuously.

I waited a lot but the screen or the downloading process did not advance.

Screenshot

[image: Downloading components in Android Studio Setup Wizard]